# How do I get the words in black to fit around the word in red like in my design using css and html

Tags: html, css, spacing

`enter code here`[reference photo to go along with question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgu6d.png)
`enter code here`[my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh2q3.png)
`enter code here`[my hmtl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KNHD.png)

I was thinking maybe I'd have to break "Pages from a" "Love" and "Manifesto" into 3 separate chunks, but I don't know how to get "Pages from a" and "Manifesto" to fit around the word love like how I've designed it. I really don't want to use an image of it if I don't have to, I'd rather learn the proper way.

I'm new to coding and I tried to look around and figure this out on my own, but if I'm being honest I don't even know how to search for a solution or where to even start to go about this because I just don't know enough about the topic to know if what I'm seeing will even help.

Please help!

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1{

    color: black;
    font-family: fino;
    text-align: center;
}

.love{
    font-family: adorn-smooth-pomander, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class=title>
        <h1>
            Pages from a <span class="love">Love</span> 
            Manifesto 
        </h1>
    </div>  

    
        <h2>
            Devised by Dom Torrez | Department of Theatre Art
        </h2>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code directly to your post instead of a screenshot? It would make it way easier to help you.

Comment: sorry! I just added it!

Answer (score 2):

Since the element `.love` is a child of the `h1` you can position the `.love` absolutely and position relative on the `h1`. Then set the ***top*** and ***left*** position to position it relative to its parent element.

Add the h2 element to the title so flex can be used on title with `flex-direction` set to `column`. Repeat flex and column flex direction on h1 element so the children will stack. Wrap the first section in a span and give it a class so it can be nudged to the left 1rem. Style love element with ***cursive*** and ***love*** class. Then wrap the first letter of ***love*** in a span tag and give it a class so it can be enlarged using `font-size`.

`h2` element style and add ***flex*** and ***justify-content: center***, then further adjust with ***margin***. Add padding to accommodate the ***love*** characters.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: fino;
  display: flex;
  /* flex allows ease of centering elements */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* set flex direction as column */
  align-items: end;
  /* center items */
  position: relative;
  /* set position to relative */
  padding-left: 3.8rem;
  /* this makes space for the love characters */
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

h2 {
  /* add flex to h2 element for centering */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: -.5rem;
}

.big {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.first {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.love {
  /* style font to similar of the logo */
  font-family: adorn-smooth-pomander, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  /* position absolute to remove element from page flow */
  top: -.7rem;
  /* top set to the top position of next element set to position relative */
  left: 0;
  /* left set to the left position of next element set to position relative */
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.cursive {
  /* helper class to style love */
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class=title>
  <h1>
    <span class="first">PAGES FROM A </span>
    <span class="love cursive">
      <span class="big">L</span>ove
    </span> 
    MANIFESTO
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Devised by Dom Torrez | Department of Theatre Art
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i don't think you should do this in pure HTML/CSS at all.

The proper way to do it is probably using an `svg` or actually an Image.

But if you insist on doing it with CSS, here you go

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: fino;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.pages {
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.love {
  font-family: adorn-smooth-pomander, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: initial;
  color: red;
  float: left;
}

.ove {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .45em;
  line-height: 0.5;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
 <div class=title>
   <h1>
     <span class="pages">Pages from a</span> <span class="love">L<span class="ove">ove</span></span><br> Manifesto
   </h1>
 </div>


 <h2>
   Devised by Dom Torrez | Department of Theatre Art
 </h2>
```

I think the `float` was your missing puzzle piece to wrap the rest around the "Love".
Now you have to change the position of the rest of the text with either negative `margin`s or `transfrom: translate`. But again, i would advise to not do this, because you would only work with "[Magic Numbers](https://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/)" and it's easy to break.